# reporting services with restful web service

Tags: sql, rest, service, web, reporting

I have very simple asp.net restful (web api) web service; let say HelloWord

```
public string GetHelloWorld(string name)
{
    return "Hello, " + name;
}
```

the method is under HomeController.

The result of this when I call via firefox (http://localhost/api/Home/?name=John) is 
hello,  John

How to consume the XML output into reporting services?

I also browse to data dynamics report (www.datadynamics.com). After see the walkthrough, it seems to me that it's client side reporting as opposed to server side reporting (i.e.: SQL Server Reporting Services). Is there anyway I can use data dynamics at server side (on top of reporting services)?

Thank you.

Koronx